# How to set the value of a string to all the values of a dropdownlist asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dropdownlist that is populated from a database, when a user clicks the add all button on the web page I want to set the value of a string 'milestones' to a comma delimited string that holds all the values of the dropdownlist. Is there a simple way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Linq to select all items of the `DropDownList`, use `String.Join` to concat them:

```
string milestoneNames = string.Join(",", 
    ddlMileStone.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Select(i => i.Text));
```

If you want all values instead:

```
string milestoneValues = string.Join(",", 
    ddlMileStone.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Select(i => i.Value));
```

Comment: It was just the names that I wanted to get so the first example worked just fine, thank you very much!

Comment: @dtsg: From .NET 4 `String.Join` accepts an `IEnumerable<T>`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 3):

Use [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx):

```
string[] ddlValues = ddl.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Select(x => x.Text).ToArray();
string milestones = string.Join(",", ddlValues));
```

Answer (score 1):

This could work for you as well.

```
string milestones = string.Join(",", ddl.Items.ToArray());
```

Comment: Sorry that doesn't compile?

Answer (score 0):

```
DropDownList d = new DropDownList();
d.Items.Add(new ListItem("1", "Foo"));
d.Items.Add(new ListItem("2", "Bar"));
string[] items = d.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();
```